# How to change mysql database directory on Xampp?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have my old databases in D:/data and I just did a fresh install of xampp in C:/xampp, I've changed to `datadir = "D:/data"` in my new my.ini file but it doesn't work properly.

PhpMyadmin shows all my old databases, but when I try to delete one it says it's corrupted, and my php files doesn't connect to my databases...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**same thing happend for me also**

It is because of You might forgot to copy the ibdata* file. You may expect this file to be located within the respective database folders just like the other related files, but you would be wrong.

My ibdata file was located at mysql/data/ibdata1; as soon as I copied that to the new location everything was good again.

Hope it will help!! :)

Comment: Tried copying ibdata1 and also ib_logfile* from C:/xampp/mysql/data to D:/data and also the other way, didn't work :(